# Java spring form checkbox

Tags: java, spring

Does anyone have a good example of how to use the check box form option in spring. I am interested in the serverside code mostly. Do I need to have an xml bean?

eg

```
<bean id="" class"" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by xml bean?

Comment: edited post, that type of bean inside the file-web.xml

Comment: No, you don't need to declare any bean in XML. Spring MVC uses annotations. Read the reference manual, which contains a link to a repository of sample applications (petclinic, for example). http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Answer (score 1):

I have a sample for you [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-checkbox-and-checkboxes-example/) for check box  support in Spring. But these are without annotations . As @JB Nizet  says , it would be lot easier with annotations .